# wrong perspective image after taking picture on accelerometer supported blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, rotation, orientation, image, exif

There is a **perspective image issue** when I read a picture that is taken from the camera. When the direction is north, the picture looks like needed to be rotated 270 degrees. When the direction is east, picture should be rotated 180 degrees. But it's good when the direction is west. I tried [getMetaData()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#getMetaData%28%29).[getKeyValue("orientation")](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/control/MetaDataControl.html#getKeyValue%28java.lang.String%29) in EncodedImage for producing a good rotating formula, but it returned empty string. Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: which device and which OS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution here: 
https://gist.github.com/3788313

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage;

public class ExifRotate {

    /**
     * Flip the image horizontally.
     */
    public static final int FLIP_H = 1;

    /**
     * Flip the image vertically.
     */
    public static final int FLIP_V = 2;

    /**
     * Flip the image horizontally and vertically.
     */
    public static final int FLIP_HV = 3;

    /**
     * Rotate the image 90 degrees clockwise.
     */
    public static final int FLIP_90CW = 4;

    /**
     * Rotate the image 90 degrees counter-clockwise.
     */
    public static final int FLIP_90CCW = 5;

    /**
     * Rotate the image 180 degrees.
     */
    public static final int FLIP_180 = 6;

    private final static int read2bytes(InputStream in) throws IOException  {
        return in.read() << 8 | in.read();
    }

    private final static int readByte(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        return in.read();
    }

    public static Bitmap readImageFromFile(String filename, int width, int height) throws IOException {
        EncodedImage img = null;
        byte[] data = null;

        FileConnection file = null;
        try {
            file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filename, Connector.READ);
            int fileSize = (int) file.fileSize();
            if (fileSize == 0) {
                throw new IOException("File is empty");
            }

            data = new byte[fileSize];
            InputStream input = file.openInputStream();
            input.read(data);
            input.close();

            img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length);

            int orientation = -1;
            if ( filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( data );
                orientation = getRotation(is);
            }

            if ( orientation == 2 ) {
                return rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_H);
            } else if ( orientation == 3 ) {
                return rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_180);
            } else if ( orientation == 4 ) {
                return rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_V);
            } else if ( orientation == 5 ) {
                Bitmap tmp = rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_H);
                tmp = rotateBitmap(tmp, ImageUtil.FLIP_90CCW);
                return tmp;
            } else if ( orientation == 6 ) {
                return rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_90CW);
            } else if ( orientation == 7 ) {
                Bitmap tmp = rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_H);
                tmp = rotateBitmap(tmp, ImageUtil.FLIP_90CW);
                return tmp;
            } else if ( orientation == 8 ) {
                return rotateBitmap(img.getBitmap(), ImageUtil.FLIP_90CCW);
            } else {
                return img.getBitmap();
            }
        } finally {
            if (file != null) {
                try { file.close(); }
                catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getRotation(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        int [] exif_data = new int[100];
        int n_flag = 0, set_flag = 0;
        int is_motorola = 0;

        /* Read File head, check for JPEG SOI + Exif APP1 */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            exif_data[i] = readByte(in);

        if (exif_data[0] != 0xFF || exif_data[1] != 0xD8 || exif_data[2] != 0xFF || exif_data[3] != 0xE1)
            return -2;

        /* Get the marker parameter length count */
        int length = read2bytes(in);
        // exif_data = new int[length];

        /* Length includes itself, so must be at least 2 */
        /* Following Exif data length must be at least 6 */
        if (length < 8)
            return -1;
        length -= 8;
        /* Read Exif head, check for "Exif" */
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            exif_data[i] = in.read();

        if (exif_data[0] != 0x45 || exif_data[1] != 0x78 || exif_data[2] != 0x69 || exif_data[3] != 0x66 || exif_data[4] != 0 || exif_data[5] != 0)
            return -1;

        /* Read Exif body */
        length = length > exif_data.length ? exif_data.length : length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            exif_data[i] = in.read();

        if (length < 12)
            return -1; /* Length of an IFD entry */

        /* Discover byte order */
        if (exif_data[0] == 0x49 && exif_data[1] == 0x49)
            is_motorola = 0;
        else if (exif_data[0] == 0x4D && exif_data[1] == 0x4D)
            is_motorola = 1;
        else
            return -1;

        /* Check Tag Mark */
        if (is_motorola == 1) {
            if (exif_data[2] != 0)
                return -1;
            if (exif_data[3] != 0x2A)
                return -1;
        } else {
            if (exif_data[3] != 0)
                return -1;
            if (exif_data[2] != 0x2A)
                return -1;
        }

        /* Get first IFD offset (offset to IFD0) */
        int offset;
        if (is_motorola == 1) {
            if (exif_data[4] != 0)
                return -1;
            if (exif_data[5] != 0)
                return -1;
            offset = exif_data[6];
            offset <<= 8;
            offset += exif_data[7];
        } else {
            if (exif_data[7] != 0)
                return -1;
            if (exif_data[6] != 0)
                return -1;
            offset = exif_data[5];
            offset <<= 8;
            offset += exif_data[4];
        }
        if (offset > length - 2)
            return -1; /* check end of data segment */

        /* Get the number of directory entries contained in this IFD */
        int number_of_tags;
        if (is_motorola == 1) {
            number_of_tags = exif_data[offset];
            number_of_tags <<= 8;
            number_of_tags += exif_data[offset + 1];
        } else {
            number_of_tags = exif_data[offset + 1];
            number_of_tags <<= 8;
            number_of_tags += exif_data[offset];
        }
        if (number_of_tags == 0)
            return -1;
        offset += 2;

        /* Search for Orientation Tag in IFD0 */
        for (;;) {
            if (offset > length - 12)
                return -1; /* check end of data segment */
            /* Get Tag number */
            int tagnum;
            if (is_motorola == 1) {
                tagnum = exif_data[offset];
                tagnum <<= 8;
                tagnum += exif_data[offset + 1];
            } else {
                tagnum = exif_data[offset + 1];
                tagnum <<= 8;
                tagnum += exif_data[offset];
            }
            if (tagnum == 0x0112)
                break; /* found Orientation Tag */
            if (--number_of_tags == 0)
                return -1;
            offset += 12;
        }

        /*
         * if (set_flag==1) { Set the Orientation value if (is_motorola==1) {
         * exif_data[offset+2] = 0; Format = unsigned short (2 octets)
         * exif_data[offset+3] = 3; exif_data[offset+4] = 0; Number Of
         * Components = 1 exif_data[offset+5] = 0; exif_data[offset+6] = 0;
         * exif_data[offset+7] = 1; exif_data[offset+8] = 0; exif_data[offset+9]
         * = set_flag; exif_data[offset+10] = 0; exif_data[offset+11] = 0; }
         * else { exif_data[offset+2] = 3; Format = unsigned short (2 octets)
         * exif_data[offset+3] = 0; exif_data[offset+4] = 1; Number Of
         * Components = 1 exif_data[offset+5] = 0; exif_data[offset+6] = 0;
         * exif_data[offset+7] = 0; exif_data[offset+8] = set_flag;
         * exif_data[offset+9] = 0; exif_data[offset+10] = 0;
         * exif_data[offset+11] = 0; } }
         */
        // else {
        /* Get the Orientation value */
        if (is_motorola == 1) {
            if (exif_data[offset + 8] != 0)
                return -1;
            set_flag = exif_data[offset + 9];
        } else {
            if (exif_data[offset + 9] != 0)
                return -1;
            set_flag = exif_data[offset + 8];
        }
        if (set_flag > 8)
            return -1;
        // }

        /* Write out Orientation value */

        if (n_flag == 1)
            System.out.println("set_flag " + set_flag);
        else
            System.out.println("set_flag " + set_flag);

        return set_flag;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap src, int operation) {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();

        int[] inPixels = new int[width*height];
        src.getARGB(inPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int w = width;
        int h = height;

        int newX = 0;
        int newY = 0;
        int newW = w;
        int newH = h;
        switch (operation) {
        case FLIP_H:
            newX = width - (x + w);
            break;
        case FLIP_V:
            newY = height - (y + h);
            break;
        case FLIP_HV:
            newW = h;
            newH = w;
            newX = y;
            newY = x;
            break;
        case FLIP_90CW:
            newW = h;
            newH = w;
            newX = height - (y + h);
            newY = x;
            break;
        case FLIP_90CCW:
            newW = h;
            newH = w;
            newX = y;
            newY = width - (x + w);
            break;
        case FLIP_180:
            newX = width - (x + w);
            newY = height - (y + h);
            break;
        }

        int[] newPixels = new int[newW * newH];
        int index, newRow, newCol, newIndex;

        if ( operation == FLIP_H ) {
            for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    index = row * width + col;
                    newRow = row;
                    newCol = w - col - 1;
                    newIndex = newRow * newW + newCol;
                    newPixels[newIndex] = inPixels[index];
                }
            }
        } else if ( operation == FLIP_V ) {
            for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    index = row * width + col;
                    newRow = h - row - 1;
                    newCol = col;
                    newIndex = newRow * newW + newCol;
                    newPixels[newIndex] = inPixels[index];
                }
            }
        } else if ( operation == FLIP_HV ) {
            for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    index = row * width + col;
                    newRow = col;
                    newCol = row;
                    newIndex = newRow * newW + newCol;
                    newPixels[newIndex] = inPixels[index];
                }
            }
        } else if ( operation == FLIP_90CW ) {
            for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    index = row * width + col;
                    newRow = col;
                    newCol = h - row - 1;
                    newIndex = newRow * newW + newCol;
                    newPixels[newIndex] = inPixels[index];
                }
            }
        } else if ( operation == FLIP_90CCW ) {
            for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    index = row * width + col;
                    newRow = w - col - 1;
                    newCol = row;
                    newIndex = newRow * newW + newCol;
                    newPixels[newIndex] = inPixels[index];
                }
            }
        } else if ( operation == FLIP_180 ) {
            for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    index = row * width + col;
                    newRow = h - row - 1;
                    newCol = w - col - 1;
                    newIndex = newRow * newW + newCol;
                    newPixels[newIndex] = inPixels[index];
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap dst = new Bitmap( newW, newH );
        dst.setARGB(newPixels, 0, newW, 0, 0, newW, newH);

        return dst;
    }

}
```